# REST Web API: JSON to C# Object based off of query path

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, marshalling

I have a C# application that queries a REST Web API.

Queries return JSON objects. I am attempting to (un)marshal these objects to C#.
I use System.Text.Json library to perform the (un)marshaling.
Different query paths return different types of Objects, and I have a Dictionary which is used to determine which data type we should be expecting based of of the query path that was used.

```
public static class ModelTypes
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> all = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "achievements", typeof(List<Achievement>) }
    };
    public static Type GetTypeFromPath(string path)
    {
        if (all.ContainsKey(path)) return all[path];
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that contains a HttpClient object name client.
I have written a function that performs a standard GET request to the API and returns a C# object of type T specified when calling the function.

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string path)
{
    Task<Stream> streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(path);
    return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(await streamTask);
}
```

Then in the application I want to actually call this function, but I can not seem to substitute the type returned from the GetTypeFromPath() function for T.

```
string path = "achievements";
Type type = ModelTypes.GetTypeFromPath(path);
if (type != null)
{
    var result = await api.Get<type>(path); // <--- Red squiggly under "type"
}
else ...
```

If I hard code in a type for example:

```
var result = await api.Get<List<Achievement>>(path);
foreach (Achievement achievement in result) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(achievement.Name);
}
```

Everything performs as expected and console prints out the Name for every achievement in the list.

Any advice on how I can simply use a generic Get(string path)?
How do dynamically specify what T is as opposed to hard coding it?
Perhaps there is a better way this can be done...

Comment: Have you tried the word dynamic instead of type

Comment: I tried using dynamic, which solves the error in calling the Get<dynamic>(path) function, but then the JSON deserializer does not know which type it is supposed to deserialize to inside of the function.

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to do. however it does not allow my to use the "type" variable as "TValue" as it is run time variable and not a hard coded "Type".

I am wondering what is the point of a generic here if I can not supply a dynamic type, only a hard coded static one.
Maybe it is just not possible, I am unsure...

Comment: Rather than deserializing to some generic parameter type, use the non-generic overload [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(Stream, Type, JsonSerializerOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_DeserializeAsync_System_IO_Stream_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and pass in the type.

Answer (score 0):

I realized afterwards you are trying to deserialize your string to a type that you are defining in Type.

```
    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string path)
    {
        Task<Stream> streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(path);
        return (T)await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(await streamTask, typeof(T));
    }
```

Instead of defining `T` as a `TValue` to `DeserializeAsync`, you have to pass the `Type` as an argument to the method. Also, since that method returns an object, you have to cast it to the return Type as well in your return statement.